# Iterate every 2 elements from list at a time

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Having list as ,

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

How can i iterate every two elements at a time ?

I am trying this ,

```
for v, w in zip(l[:-1],l[1:]):
    print [v, w]
```

and getting output is like ,

```
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 5]
[5, 6]
[6, 7]
[7, 8]
[8, 9]
[9, 0]
```

Expected output is

```
[1,2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7, 8]
[9,10]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `iter`:

```
>>> seq = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> it = iter(seq)
>>> for x in it:
...     print (x, next(it))
...     
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7, 8]
[9, 10]
```

You can also use the [`grouper` recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) from itertools:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
...         "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
...         # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
...         args = [iter(iterable)] * n
...         return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
... 
>>> for x, y in grouper(seq, 2):
...     print (x, y)
...     
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7, 8]
[9, 10]
```

Answer (score 15):

You could do it your way, just add a step part to the slice to make both slices skip a number:

```
for v, w in zip(l[::2],l[1::2]):  # No need to end at -1 because that's the default
    print [v, w]
```

But I like helper generators:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    i = iter(iterable)
    while True:
       yield i.next(), i.next()

for v, w in pairwise(l):
    print v, w
```

Answer (score 12):

What's wrong with:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
for j in range(0, len(l), 2):
    print(l[j: j + 2])
        
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7, 8]
```

assuming the lists have even number of elements.

Answer (score 9):

One solution is

```
for v, w in zip(l[::2],l[1::2]):
    print [v, w]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
In [180]: lst = range(1,11)

In [181]: for i in zip(*[iter(lst)]*2):
   .....:     print i
   .....:
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(5, 6)
(7, 8)
(9, 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
>>> map(None,*[iter(l)]*2)
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
>>>
```

Comment: how to make it list of lists instead of list of tuples?

Comment: l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
l2=map(None,*[iter(l)]*2)
print(l2)

gives map object instead of k,v pairs.


print(list(l2))

gives

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, just a different approach.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
chunks = [l[x:x+2] for x in range(0,len(l),2)]
print(chunks)
```

Answer (score 1):

For people who came here wanting to walk through a list with very long steps and don't want to use lots of memory upfront, you can just do this.

Python 2.7:

```
import itertools

def step_indices(length, step):
    from_indices = xrange(0, length, step)
    to_indices = itertools.chain(xrange(step, length, step), [None])
    for i, j in itertools.izip(from_indices, to_indices):
        yield i, j

the_list = range(1234)
for i, j in step_indices(len(the_list), 100):
    up_to_100_values = the_list[i:j]
```

Python 3:

```
import itertools

def step_indices(length, step):
    from_indices = range(0, length, step)
    to_indices = itertools.chain(range(step, length, step), [None])
    for i, j in zip(from_indices, to_indices):
        yield i, j

the_list = list(range(1234))
for i, j in step_indices(len(the_list), 100):
    up_to_100_values = the_list[i:j]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `map` (with slightly different syntax than other answers). In a list with an odd number of elements, the last element is paired with `None`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> map(None, a[::2], a[1::2])
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10), (11, None)]
```

You can modify the function to return e.g. lists instead of tuples:

```
>>> map(lambda x,y:[x,y], a[::2], a[1::2])
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, None]]

>>> for e in map(lambda x,y:[x,y], a[::2], a[1::2]):
...     print e
... 
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7, 8]
[9, 10]
[11, None]
```

**Edit**: this solution only works on Python 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple solution that works:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
chunks = [(l[i-1], l[i]) for i in range(1, len(l))] 
print(chunks )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't work, it prints `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 0)]`. Elements are being repeated. You need to add a step to your range.