# Iterate over a list, getting multiple items at once

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have a list of numbers that I want to iterate over in pairs, but without skipping items.
For instance:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
for one,two in myList:
    print(one,two)
```

which I want to print,

```
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
```

I am currently using the list index and am manually getting the additional items, but I want to know if there is a "proper" way to do this.

Comment: Funny enough, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752610/iterate-every-2-elements-from-list-at-a-time) is the answer to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that works is usually the proper way...

You could in principle zip the list with a deferred slice of itself:

```py
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
for one,two in zip(myList, myList[1:]):
    print(one,two, sep=",")
```

Note that `zip` ends on the shortest given iterable, so it will finish on the shorter slice; no need to also shorten the full `myList` parameter.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the list with itself, just offset by 1 item.

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
for x, y in zip(myList, myList[1:]):
    print(f'{x},{y}')
```

which prints:

```
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
```